# How do I pass state to BottomNavigationBar pages in Flutter with redux?

Tags: flutter, redux

So normally I would have have a list of widgets and a current index indicator inside my homepage widget whenever using a bottom navigation bar. Or at least that's what I've seen most basic tutorials use.

```
body: _widgets.elementAt(_currentIndex)
onTap: (index) {
    setState(() {
        _currentIndex = index;
    }
}
```

I want to transition to a way of managing state with redux now though, and I'm not exactly sure how to handle this change within my home widget.

The body field of my Scaffold now becomes

```
body: StoreConnector<AppState, AppViewModel>(
        converter: (Store<AppState> store) => AppViewModel.create(store),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AppViewModel viewModel) => // I should have the default page here
      )
```

Each page widget should take the view model as a parameter.

```
// page widget example
class BrowsePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title = "Browse recipes";
  final AppViewModel model;

  BrowsePage(this.model);

  @override
  _BrowseState createState() => _BrowseState();
}
```

So I don't know how to organize my widget list this way. I can no longer have a widget list during initialization since I don't have access to the view model there (or at least I don't think I do). I also don't I can access the view model in the `onTap` callback.

So how should I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can manage `BottomNavigationBar` with `Redux`.

You need a model, state, action & reducer for managing your tabs.

Let's assume the following:

**Model** - `TabModel`

**State** - `TabState`

**Action** - `ChangeTabAction`

**Reducer** - `tabReducer`

Create a `TabModel` class to customize your `BottomNavigationBar` items like title, icon, color, etc.

**TabModel**

```
class TabModel {
  final String title;
  final String iconPath; // If you are using Material icons, then use IconData
  final Color color;

  const TabModel({
    @required this.title,
    @required this.iconPath,
    @required this.color,
  });
}
```

Create a `TabState` which will store the current active index with the default index set to `0`.

**TabState**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

@immutable
class TabState {
  final int currentIndex;

  const TabState({this.currentIndex});

  factory TabState.initial() => const TabState(currentIndex: 0);

  TabState copyWith({int currentIndex}) {
    return TabState(
      currentIndex: currentIndex ?? this.currentIndex,
    );
  }

  dynamic toJson() => {
    'currentIndex': currentIndex,
  };

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '${const JsonEncoder.withIndex(' ').convert(this)}';
  }
}
```

Create `TabAction` which will take in the index position of the new tab. We will use this action to switch tabs.

**TabAction**

```
class ChangeTabAction {
  const ChangeTabAction(this.index);

  final int index;
}
```

Create `TabReducer` that will handle the dispatched actions & will change the `TabState`.

**TabReducer**

```
final tabReducer = TypedReducer(_tabActionReducer);

TabState _tabActionReducer(TabState state, dynamic action) {
  if (action is ChangeTabAction) {
    return changeTab(state, action);
  }
  return state;
}

TabState changeTab(TabState state, dynamic action) {
  return state.copyWith(
    currentIndex: action.index,
  );
}
```

Pass this `tabReducer` to your main reducer, in my case, it is `appReducer`.

```
AppState appReducer(AppState state, dynamic action) {
  return state.copyWith(
    tabState: tabReducer(state.tabState, action),
    ..., // Other reducers
  );
}
```

Your `AppState` should look something like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AppState {
  final TabState tabState;
  ... // Other states

  const AppState({
    @required this.tabState,
    .. // other states
  });

  factory AppState.initial() {
    return AppState(
      tabState: TabState.initial(),
    );
  }

  AppState copyWith({
    TabState tabState,
  }) {
    return AppState(
      tabState: tabState ?? this.tabState,
    );
  }

  dynamic toJson() => {
    'tabState': tabState,
  };

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '${const JsonEncoder.withIndent(' ').convert(this)}';
  }
}
```

Now, we'll create our UI & will handle the `BottomNavigationBar` as follows:

Let's suppose your `BottomNavigationBar` is in `HomeWidget`.

```
class HomeWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StoreConnector(
      converter: (Store<AppState> store) => AppViewModel.create(store),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AppViewModel viewModel) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: IndexedStack(
            index: viewModel.tabState.currentIndex,
            children: [
              Dashboard(), // Replace these widgets with your widgets
              SomeOtherWidget(),
              Settings(),
              MyProfile(),
            ],
          ),
          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
            currentIndex: viewModel.tabState.currentIndex,
            type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
            items: viewModel.buildItems(),
            onTap: viewModel.changeTab,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

My `viewModel` looks something like this. You might need to modify your's `AppViewModel`.

```
class AppViewModel {
  final TabState tabState;
  final void Function(int) changeTab;

  const AppViewModel({
    @required this.tabState,
    @required this.changeTab,
  });

  static AppViewModel create(Store<AppState> store) {
    return AppViewModel(
      tabState: store.state.tabState,
      changeTab: (index) => store.dispatch(
        ChangeTabAction(index),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<BottomNavigationBarItem> buildItems() {
    return [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: SvgPicture.asset(Assets.svg.home,
          color: tabState.currentIndex == 0 ? primaryColor : neutralColor,
        ),
        title: const Text(Strings.home),
      ),

      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: SvgPicture.asset(Assets.svg.other,
          color: tabState.currentIndex == 1 ? primaryColor : neutralColor,
        ),
        title: const Text(Strings.other),
      ),

      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: SvgPicture.asset(Assets.svg.settings,
          color: tabState.currentIndex == 2 ? primaryColor : neutralColor,
        ),
        title: const Text(Strings.settings),
      ),

      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: SvgPicture.asset(Assets.svg.myProfile,
          color: tabState.currentIndex == 3 ? primaryColor : neutralColor,
        ),
        title: const Text(Strings.myProfile),
      ),
    ];
  }
}
```